# read oracle sql file using python and fetch results in to CSV file

Tags: python, sql, oracle, csv, cx-oracle

I am beginner to python and want to read a sql file from python and fetch those results in to CSV file. I have tried usin CX_oracle to connect to oracle database. It works when i directly give the sql query in the code. But, I am not sure how to read a sql file from python.

Here is the code which worked when i gave sql query directly in the code:

```
import csv 
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('XCM/XCM@home.com:1500/HOME')
cursor = con.cursor()
csv_file = open("exp.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
r = cursor.execute("select * from home_parties where CREATION_DATE >= trunc(sysdate)")
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
con.close()
csv_file.close()
```

I tried the below code to fetch from sql file which has the same sql query as mentioned in the above code - sample.sql but it dint work

```
import csv
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('XCM/XCM@home.com:1500/HOME')
cursor = con.cursor()
csv_file = open("exp.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter='|', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
f = open('C:/Users/home1/sample.sql')
full_sql = f.read()
r = cursor.execute(full_sql)
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
con.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Kindly help me out!!

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Did you get an error?  If so, what error?  On what line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the sql file might be read within a ***for*** loop *line* by *line* such as

```py
import csv 
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('XCM/XCM@home.com:1500/HOME')
cursor = con.cursor()

sql=""
with open("C:/Users/home1/sample.sql") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        sql += line

f_out = open("exp.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
con.close()
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

considering the SQL statement to be spreaded across multiple lines

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a sample.sql file in the same directory with the query as the first line. This would read the SQL query from that file, then execute the query and save the result into a CSV file named "exp.csv".

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('XCM/XCM@home.com:1500/HOME')
cursor = con.cursor()

import pandas as pd
with open('sample.sql') as f:
    sql_query_string = f.readline();
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query_string, con)

sql_query.to_csv("exp.csv", sep='|')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i dont want the sql query to be seen in the code. My actual SQL Query is pretty big. So instead of putting the sql query directly in the code, i want to use it as a file and Python should read that SQL file - sample.sql and retrieve data in to CSV.  could you please help on how to read the SQL file from Python and fetch data in to CSV file.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: If I understood you correctly this would do the job.

Comment: cannot open the connection, so voted down. sorry.